# Java switch using methods

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am wanting to call methods from an object from a switch statement.
Here, I am switching on a `String`:

```
switch (properties.getProperty("my.property")) { // getProperty() retuns a String
  case contains("something"):
    doSomething();
    break;
}
```

Can I execute methods of the `switch`'ed object like this?  Basically I'm trying to avoid doing:

```
case properties.getProperty("my.property").contains("something"):
```

I'm pretty sure it's a lost cause, but perhaps I've missed something...

I've tried using `contains()` and `.contains()` to no avail.  Should I just stop trying to be lazy?  Or is there a way to do this?

Comment: use if, not switch. switch works only on constants comparisons.

Comment: in essence, I should stop trying to be lazy :)

Comment: I don't see why this is like `.With` at all - that's for setting several properties on a single object, it's *not* for choosing one set of statements to execute based on an existing property.

Comment: I'm not a VB.NET programmer, I just vaguely remember you were able to do this type of syntax

Comment: Well look at the question you linked to. Do those examples look like what you're trying to do?

Comment: The .Net "With" and "Using" functions are completely different from the Switch (Select Case in .Net) function.  I assume that what you're trying to do is something like 'With properties' and then do a switch on .getProperty("my.property"), correct?

Comment: basically.  if you read my question @Taegost, i was just curious if this was possible. my initial thought was "no" but thought i'd ask.  I ended up just doing an `if` so i can call `contains`.

Comment: @JonSkeet took all references to With out, as it *was* misleading.

Comment: @sircapsalot - Thank you for clarifying your question, that answered my previous question

Comment: Right, that's definitely clearer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't. `switch`/`case` statements are for simple "this constant value maps to this set of actions; this constant value maps to this set of actions; ...".

If you need more complex processing, you should just use `if` statements.

Comment: Well met, Jon. Thanks for this.  That was my understanding of the `switch` statement, but I wanted to solidify my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to use switch you can do that:

```
  switch("true") {
         case aFunctionThatReturnsTrueOrFalse():

 }
```

This isn't really proper, but it should work tough

Comment: This is (should be?) a compile time error. You can't put booleans in a switch.

Answer (score 1):

As @JonSkeet pointed out already, you can't generalize `switch` statements to do what you're trying to do.

In some cases however you can "trick" it: with strings, for example, you can use a `switch` statement for exact matches. In your case you can also do it in a **slightly obfuscated** way with **regex**:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("something|else");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(properties.getProperty("my.property"));

switch(matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : "") {
case "something":
    doSomething();
    break;
case "else":
    doSomethingElse();
    break;
default:
    doDefault();
}
```

I don't think the above offers any improvement over the obvious approach with `if`s:

```
if(prop.contains("something")) {
    doSomething();
} else if(prop.contains("else")) {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

The second version is both simpler and more readable. Possibly faster, too.